# Symfony Acl implementation

Tags: symfony, acl

Does Symfony Acl can implement Acl System like this:
http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf
This's concept used by Joomla (http://www.aclmanager.net/).

After researching for weeks. I'm not sure Symfony Acl can make ​​it or not. The key of difference in this case is permission with allow and deny value. Symfony's permission have not value (just mask key edit,delete, ...) but Phpgacl's permission have a value (edit:allow|deny...).

What I want? I want to break (grant new) some user's permission is granted to group or role.
Example (probably not right please refer to phpgacl).

```
A. User_A have ROLE_X.
B. ROLE_X granted 'VIEW and EDIT' to some resource (object, class).
    -- $acl->insertObjectAce($roleSecurityIdentity, $mask) // mask VIEW,EDIT
C. User_A deny `EDIT`
D. User_A have only `VIEW`.
---- and.
A. User_B have ROLE_X
B. User_B have `VIEW` and `EDIT`
```